# "No KVM" error for Windows iso file in GNOME Boxes

Tags: gnome-boxes, windows-11

I am trying to start a Windows 11 VM in GNOME Boxes, but I get the below error.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/0s6F6.png]

Comment: You'll have to reboot into your BIOS, and find the "Virtual Memory/Machine" or "KVM" setting and enable it.